# Show that $M$ is not maximal in $\mathbb Q$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

$\mathbb Q$ is a $\mathbb Z$ module. Let $M$ be a proper submodule of $\mathbb Q$.

1. Show that there is some $0 \neq b \in \mathbb Z$, such that $1/b \notin M$

If for all $b \in \mathbb Z$, $1/b \in M$, then $\mathbb Q = M$. contradiction. this is easy.

2. Show that $M \cap \mathbb Z \neq 0$. This is also easy.
3. Show that $M$ is not maximal in $\mathbb Q$. I can't figure this out.

i said that since $1/b \notin M$, we have $\mathbb Q = M + (1/b) \mathbb Z$.

i'm trying to find a contradiction from here. any help?

i also thought that if $M$ is maximal then $\mathbb Q/M$ is simple, then it is also cyclic. but this doesn't look useful.  thanks for help.

Comment: If $1/b\notin M$, can it be the case that $1/b^2 \in M + (1/b)\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @MarcPaul doesn't seem problematic to me

Comment: @MarcPaul having said that i can't see the contradiction, i would appreciate it if you can tell why it can't be the case.

Comment: @madmatician If you _begin_ by saying "$M$ contains a non-zero integer, hence wlog $1\in M$" _then_ it's problematic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\;\Bbb Q\;$ is a divisible abelian group (=divisible $\;\Bbb Z-$module), and this means that for any $\;n\in\Bbb N,\,\,q\in\Bbb Q\;$ there exists $\;p\in\Bbb Q\;$ s.t. $\;np=q\;$ .

Observe that any homomorphic image of a divisible group is also divisible, but no finite abelian group (in fact, no abelian group with finite exponent) can be divisible, so if $\;M\le\Bbb Q\;$ is maximal then $\;\Bbb Q/M\;$ is simple and thus finite (and of prime order, but we don't care about this), and thus it can't be divisible, contradiction.

Comment: "If $M \le Q$ is maximal, then $Q/M$ is simple and thus finite". Can you please explain what happened here?

Comment: $\;\Bbb Q/M\;$ simple $\;\iff\;$ it has no non-trivial normal subgroups. But this is an abelian group so *any* subgroup is normal, so it is simple iff it has no non-trivial subgroups at all $\;\iff\;$ it is of order a prime (and finite, among other things). Remember: the only abelian simple groups are those which are cyclic of primer order. I think you may have rushed a little to downvote: my answer is correct as far as I can see, though it may be out of your current knowledge. I can't know that.

Answer (score 1):

A hugely elementary proof, since I don't know any algebra:

First, wlog $M\ne0$. Hence $M$ contains a non-zero integer.

Lemma Wlog $1\in M$.

Proof: Say $n\in M\cap\Bbb Z$, $n\ne 0$. Let $M'=\frac1n M$. Then
$M$ is maximal if and only if $M'$ is maximal. QED.

Lemma If $a,b\in\Bbb Z$, $a/b\in M$, $(a,b)=1$, then $1/b\in M$.

Proof: There exist $n,m\in\Bbb Z$ with $na+mb=1$. Hence $1/b=na/b+m\in M$, since $1\in M$. QED$

So $M\ne\Bbb Q$ implies that there exist $p$ and $n$ such that $1/p^n\in M$ but $1/p^{n+1}\notin M$ (otherwise the previous lemma shows that the reciprocal of any product of powers of primes is in $M$, so $M=\Bbb Q)$).

So $M$ is a proper submodule of $\frac1p M\ne\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Why is it the case that $M$ is maximal iff $M'$ is maximal?

Comment: @madmatician Because $\phi(t)=t/n$ defines an automorphism of $\Bbb Q$. (This is also why $\frac1p M\ne\Bbb Q$ at the end...)